# What way would be best to adhere to both DRY and limit unintended functionality given this kind of design in C# or Java?

Tags: java, c#, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

Please excuse my limited paint skills, but how would I best create objects as described here(given the single-class inheritance nature of the languages): [image: diagram]

The Moon, Rocky Planet, and Asteroid classes should implement IColonizable, but the issue is that they would implement it in the exact same way, say, with a simple getter.  In this case, I would assume it would be better to put the functionality into the parent class Body.  However, I would then be giving the GasGiant class the ability to getOwner() when I do not want this functionality to exist.

The best solution I can come up with is implementing getOwner in the Body class, but only inheriting the IColonizable interface in the desired classes, then maybe when getOwner() is called in GasGiant, I could override with an exception.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Always prefer *Composition* (interfaces) over *inheritance* (base classes). Dog is an animal, bird is an animal. You dont implement bark in animal and explode the bird when it tries to bark.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @TheGeneral, this was my first instinct too, but say the implementation of bark was very lengthy and complex, but the same for all barking animals, and Animal was already a fairly complex abstract class.  Would you really recommend copy/pasting the bark implementation to all barking animals?

Comment: You would inject the `BarkingService` with Dependency Injection to implement the contract (interface) your class supports

Comment: So you would call a new BarkingService attribute for every class you wished to have barking capabilities, since having a BarkingService attribute wouldn't make sense for a generic animal right?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intermediate base classes which derives from or extends `Body` and implements `IColonizable` (specialization of `Body` which you would like to implement `IColonizable`):

```
interface IColonizable
{ 
  Owner GetOwner():
}

abstract class Body 
{
}

abstract class ColonizableBody : Body, IColonizable
{
  public Owner GetOwner()
  {
  }
}

class Planet : Body 
{
}

class ColonizablePlanet : ColonizableBody 
{
}

class GasGiant : Planet
{
}

class RockyPlanet : ColonizablePlanet
{
}

class Moon : ColonizableBody 
{
}

class Asteroid : ColonizableBody 
{
}
```

---

As mentioned before you generally should favor composition over inheritance. Instead of *"An object is"* you go like *"An object has"*: *"A `Planet` has a `Body`"* or *"A `Moon` has a `ColonizableBody`"*. This is more natural. More natural means the created data structures and their relations are easier to understand, maintain, test and to extend:

```
interface IBody
{
  double GetMass();
}

interface IColonizable
{
  Owner GetOwner();
}

interface IColonizableBody : IColonizable, IBody
{
}

interface IPlanet : IBody
{
  IBody GetBody();
}

class Body : IBody
{
  public Body()
  {
  }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return 10000; }
}

class Planet : IPlanet
{
  private IBody _body;

  public Planet()
  {
    this._body = new Body();
  }

  // Implementation of IPlanet
  public IBody GetBody() { return this._body; }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return this._body.GetMass(); }
}    

class ColonizableBody : IColonizableBody
{
  private Owner _owner;
  private IBody _body;

  private ColonizableBody(Owner owner)
  {
    this._owner = owner;
    this._body = new Body();
  }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return this._body.GetMass(); }

  // Implementation of IColonizable
  public Owner GetOwner() { return this._owner; }
}
    
class Moon : IColonizableBody 
{
  private IColonizableBody _colonizableBody;

  public Moon(Owner owner)
  {
    this._colonizableBody = new ColonizableBody(owner);
  }

  // Implementation of IColonizable
  public double GetOwner() { return this._colonizableBody.GetOwner(); }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return this._colonizableBody.GetMass(); }
}

class RockyPlanet : IColonizableBody, IPlanet 
{
  private IColonizableBody _colonizableBody;

  public RockyPlanet(Owner owner)
  {
    this._colonizableBody = new ColonizableBody(owner);
  }

  // Implementation of IColonizable
  public Owner GetOwner() { return this._colonizableBody.GetOwner(); }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return this._colonizableBody.GetMass(); }

  // Implementation of IPlanet
  public IBody GetBody() { return this._colonizableBody.GetBody(); }
}


class GasGiant : IPlanet 
{
  private IBody _body;

  public GasGiant()
  {
    this._body = new Body();
  }

  // Implementation of IPlanet
  public IBody GetBody() { return this._body; }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return this._body.GetMass(); }
}

class Asteroid : IColonizableBody 
{
  private IColonizableBody _colonizableBody;

  public Moon(Owner owner)
  {
    this._colonizableBody = new ColonizableBody(owner);
  }

  // Implementation of IColonizable
  public double GetOwner() { return this._colonizableBody.GetOwner(); }

  // Implementation of IBody
  public double GetMass() { return this._colonizableBody.GetMass(); }
}
```

In an advanced scenario, you would inject the composition objects using the constructor instead of explicitly creating instances using the `new` keyword.